# Apache Slow Response Due to Queue

Tags: performance, apache, web, queue

I'm creating a web with Apache. After a couple of users log in to the web, the Apache server starts to respond slowly. I have checked that it is due to the queue of the process. It means that some users need to wait for other processes in the queue to be completed so that they can log in to the web successfully.

Does anyone know how to fix the slow response issue from Apache caused by its queue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe should customize MPM worker module configuration :

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/worker.html

Comment: Thanks, but it couldn't fix the issue